# IntelliJ IDEA - Swing application on KDE plasma strange behavior

Tags: debian, kde

I'm on Debian 10 testing, fully updated, so on KDE Plasma 5.13.5
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 EAP on Oracle JDK 1.8.181

When I open IDEA (maximized by default), this appears:

[image]

You can see I only have the maximize and close buttons.
If I resize it, the minimize button appears:

[image]

What can I do to solve this issue? It happens also on the starting projects dialog, in which case the close button goes "out" of the dialog on the upper right corner.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been tracked here : [kde issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196425)

Workaround :

Open : IntelliJ IDEA -> Help > Edit Custom Properties

and put this line :

```
suppress.focus.stealing=false
```

Note : Ide may need a restart to take action of this new property.

Answer (score 1):

Due to lack of points, posting an answer..
Did you define any KWin window rules? I'm asking since it's highly probable if you're a shortcut user and have to block all global shortcuts.

In that case, something could be wrong the rules preventing the minimize button from appearing.

About the close button in the starting projects dialog: I have this too and believe it is a (recent) bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well yeah I set a couple of shortcut (I come from Windows), I need to see what happen if I reset everything. Tommorow  at work.